# Pig Latin query for sum and count

Tags: apache-pig

I am new to Pig Latin and am trying to reproduce a simple SQL query. A sample input data table is of the form:

```
**A   B  C**
  1   3  $5
  2   4  $6
  2   5  $7
```

I would like to count the number of rows in column B and sum the row in C. Such that:

```
**A   Count(B)   Sum(C)**
  1   1          $5
  2   2          $13
```

Or in SQL:

```
Select A, count(B), Sum(C)
From Data
Group by A
```

How do I accomplish this in PIG?

Answer (score 1):

**Pig Script :**

```sql
input_data = LOAD 'input.csv' 
             USING PigStorage(',')
             AS (A:long, B:long, C:long);

input_data_grp_by_A = GROUP input_data BY A;

required_stats = FOREACH input_data_grp_by_A 
                 GENERATE group AS A,
                          COUNT(input_data.B) AS COUNT_B,
                          SUM(input_data.C) AS SUM_C;
```

**Input :**

```
1,3,5
2,4,6
2,5,7
```

**Output: required_stats**

```
(1,1,5)
(2,2,13)
```